# Net Core 2 - Entity Framework: Update-Database of different environment

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

**FACTS:**

- net core 2.0 project
- entity framework (code first)
- different appsettings.json file for different environments

  I utilize Package Manager Console to generate my DB scripts (Add-Migration, Update-Database)

If I run  PM>"Get-DbContext" it brings back info pulled from my appsettings.Development.json file GREAT, that's what I want most of the time!

**But how do I tell it to pull db variables from appsettings.Staging.json instead of development for PM commands?**

I tried creating new launchSettings.json profiles and setting "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging" but everything seems to respect that except PM.

*PS work around it to generate script with Script-Migration but I would like the fast UP and DOWN I get and wont use it to deploy to prod*

Comment: launchSettings.json is only used by Visual Studio 2017 when you hit F5 or Ctrl+F5. It's **NOT USED by ASP.NET Core itself*. You have to set environment variable in powershell or commandline (cmd.exe)

Comment: Thanks Tseng you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not well documented but you can have to changed the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT manually by running this command in Package Manager Console

```
PM> $env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Staging'
```

then you can run this command to verify it is pointing to your desired database:

```
PM> Get-DbContext
```

which will kick out

```
providerName                            databaseName          dataSource                                 options
------------                            ------------          ----------                                 -------
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer myDatabase            tcp:fake.database.windows.net,1433           None
```

then just run your commands as normal.  Example:

```
Update-Database
```

Reference to commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: It looks this only works for .net core 2.0 (which is OP's case), as mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7353).

Comment: It's not working on VS2019. Environment is not changing at the moment.

Comment: @user3172616 this is working for me on VS2019, although I did just update so might be something they've fixed.